# How to connect native action button of notification in android to button which is present on webview.?

Tags: android, react-native, webview

Basically I want to build a notification with action button and when the action button is clicked i want to perform a action which is same as clicking a button on webview .So is there any way to do?Please list all the possible approaches.

Comment: i could not show code because of some reasons,so i basically need approach only

Comment: Use React Natives Alert Component. Alert.alert("title","text",["buttonname" , onPress ]) you can set up custom buttons and pass a function to them onPress. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alert

Comment: Button on the notification > sends pending intent to activity/service > activity uses webviewclient javascript interface to call button in javascript of webview